# Win32: Can GetIpNetTable2() be used to return a list of all computers on the network?

Tags: winapi, networking, winsock

I'm not sure what `GetIpNetTable2()` actually does internally?   Can this be used in lieu of scanning each IP in a subnet, either sending ICMP Ping packet or requesting ARP?   Is it reliable or will it only have a list of IP addresses the local computer has talked with?

Overall, what is the best way to find a list of all computers IP addresses available on the network via a Windows application?

TIA!

Comment: It looks like it just retrieves information already retrieved by previous ARPs (or the IPv6 equivalent?). And do you want active or passive scanning to discover hosts?

Comment: Thanks.  Would want whatever is most reliable and fast enough to be usable.

Comment: Do you want the command like [net view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh875576(v=ws.11))?

Comment: No that is the WNET stuff that doesn't always work correctly.   I need to actually scan for the systems.  Must have to do actively since looking at the ARP cache, not everything is in there all the time.   Using SendArp time out per non existing system is about 2 seconds.  When scanning a 16bit subnet you have 65535 or so hosts to scan, that take forever, if you did it 200 threads at a time, still too long, can't create that many threads, haven't tried DNS lookups yet, If fast, guess I could limit to systems in DNS?  There must be something in 2021 to do it fast (echos can be blocked)?